# Post data using ajax without form or button submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I went through various questions on SO and docs on google.
I found jquery post occurs on button/link click or on form submit event.

I am working with facebook JS sdk. I have kept facebook login button on my page. If used is first time on site, button will appear when user sign in user's favourite movies will be store in database and then redirect to new page using ajax.

Previously I code where when user click button the action performed.

now I want it automtically check login status(this happens), post data to x.php (this page will insert into db) and then redirect to new page y.php.

I could not figureout how can I perform without `$( "a" ).click(function( event )` or `submit`.

I have coded here if someone can help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>ThenWat</title>
   </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var button;
            var userInfo;
             window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({ appId: '178812232292862',
                    status: true,
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true,
                    oauth: true});

               showLoader(true);

               function updateButton(response) {
                    button       =   document.getElementById('fb-auth');
                    userInfo     =   document.getElementById('user-info');

                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        //user is already logged in and connected
                        FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,movies,email', function(info) {
                        console.log(info.movies);
                        login(response, info);

                        });

                        button.onclick = function() {
                            FB.logout(function(response) {
                                logout(response);
                            });
                        };
                    } else {
                        //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                        button.innerHTML = 'Login';
                        button.onclick = function() {
                            showLoader(true);
                            FB.login(function(response) {
                                if (response.authResponse) {
                                    FB.api('/me', function(info) {

                                        login(response, info);
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                    showLoader(false);
                                }
                            }, {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,user_about_me'});
                        }
                    }
                }

                // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
                FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
            };
            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol
                    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());

            function login(response, info){


**var json = JSON.stringify(info.movies.data);
            var a = JSON.parse(json);       
            console.log(a);
            alert(a);**   // a I want to post to some new page 'movies_db.php' and then redirect to new page which I could not do**


                    if (response.authResponse) {
                    var accessToken                                 =   response.authResponse.accessToken;
                     userInfo.innerHTML                             = info.name         
                    button.innerHTML                               = 'Logout';
                    showLoader(false);
                   document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";
               }
            }

            function logout(response){
                userInfo.innerHTML                             =   "";
                document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML     =   "";
                document.getElementById('other').style.display =   "none";
                showLoader(false);
            }

             function showLoader(status){
                if (status)
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
                else
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
            }
         </script>
         <button id="fb-auth">Login</button>
        <div id="loader" style="display:none">
            <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="user-info"></div>
        <br />
        <div id="debug"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this could be helpful for you: [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @Pete: Thanks, but I am not sound with ajax. could you please elaborate!

Comment: there are some good examples at the bottom of that page that show you how to post variables to a url and then handle the repsonse.  [This question may show you more how to get a json reponse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261747/how-to-get-json-response-into-variable-from-a-jquery-script).  To redirect just do a `window.location` in the success response handler